# How to create attr_reader to a class dynamically

Tags: ruby

How do I create an attribute on an object dynamically and assign an object to its value?
I have the following code:

```
class Component
  def initialize
  end    
end

class BaseClass
  def initialize
  end

  # define class methods
  def self.create_component(**args)
    # create attr_accessor with name "ball"
    # set ball = Component.new
  end
end

class ChildClass < BaseClass

  create_component :name => "ball"
  create_component :name => "baseball"
  def initialize
  end
end
```

My goal is that when the ChildClass calls "create_component" method, this should create an attribute with the name provided in :name parameter and instantiate a "Component" object to this attribute.

```
object = ChildClass.new
object.ball #=> to return object reference (Component class 1)
object.baseball #=> to return object reference (Component class 2)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can define BaseClass like so:

```
class Component; end

class BaseClass
  @@components = []
  def initialize
    @@components.each do |attr|
      instance_variable_set("@#{attr}", Component.new)
    end
  end
  def self.create_component(name:)
    attr_reader name.to_sym
    @@components << name
  end
end

class ChildClass < BaseClass
  create_component :name => "ball"
  create_component :name => "baseball"
end

object = ChildClass.new

object.ball
# => #<Component:0x00007fa62fbdf3f8>

object.baseball
# => #<Component:0x00007fa62fbdf3a8>
```

Basically you do three things:

1. Create a class-level instance variable `@@components` which stores a list of the custom `attr_reader` names
2. Inside `create_component`, call `attr_reader` to create the method and also add it to the `@@components` list
3. Inside `initialize`, set initial values for each of the `@@components` (you can also give custom values for these using `initialize` arguments if you like).

Comment: Why does the `instance_variable_set` function has to be called inside `initialize` method instead of being executed right after `attr_reader name.to_sym` ?

Comment: Because `attr_reader` is called at the class level. The instance variable must be set at the instance level.

Answer (score 1):

You could do that as follows.

```
class Component
end

class BaseClass
  def create_component(name)
    self.class.send(:attr_accessor, name)
    instance_variable_set("@#{name}", Component.new)
  end
end

class ChildClass < BaseClass
end

c = ChildClass.new
c.create_component "ball"
  #=> #<Component:0x000056f36c73c2e0> 
c.create_component"baseball"
  #=> #<Component:0x000056f36c7533f0>
c.methods & [:ball, :baseball]
  #=> [:ball, :baseball] 
c.instance_variables
  #=> [:@ball, :@baseball] 
c.ball
  #=> #<Component:0x000056f36c73c2e0> 
c.baseball
  #=> #<Component:0x00005602be1eb560> 
c.ball = 1
c.ball
  #=> 1
```

Note that

```
self.class.send(:attr_accessor, name)
```

could be replaced with

```
self.class.class_eval { attr_accessor name.to_sym }
```

That the instance variables are being added to an instance of a child class of `BaseClass` is of no matter. It would be essentially the same question if they were to be added to an instance of `BaseClass`.

Answer (score 1):

This creates an instance method, such as:

```
def baseball
  @baseball ||= Component.new
end
```

For the `baseball=` it just uses regular `attr_writer`:

```
class Component
end

class BaseClass
  def self.create_component(name:)
    class_eval <<~EOB
      attr_writer :#{name}
      def #{name}
        @#{name} ||= Component.new
      end
    EOB
  end
end

class ChildClass < BaseClass
  create_component name: "ball"
  create_component name: "baseball"
end
```

This seems to work:

```
> c = ChildClass.new
> c.ball
=> #<Component:0x00007f8b270cfa58>
> c.baseball
=> #<Component:0x00007f8b270dbdd0>
```

Comment: I like this one better since you do not have to manually assign the components. As the example of the OP suggest he would like those attributes to be predefined after the object is initialized.